# How to extract all strings between two substrings from a dataframe column with null values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as follows:

```
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|index| category                                                                               |
|-----|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|1    | [{'id':'4g', 'desc':'med', 'lang':'en-US'}, {'id':'nr', 'desc':'hos', 'lang':'en-US'}] |
|-----|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|2    | [{'id':'hh', 'desc':'disc', 'lang':'en-US'}]                                           |
|-----|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|3    | NULL                                                                                   |
|-----|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
.     .                                            .                                           .
.     .                                            .                                           .
.     .                                            .                                           .
```

I want to get all the strings between `'desc'` and `'lang'` and preserve them in the same column separated by a comma

```
+---------------------+
| index | category    |
|-------|-------------|
| 1     | 'med','hos' |
|-------|-------------|
| 2     | 'disc'      |
|-------|-------------|
| 3     |  NULL       |
|-------|-------------|
```

I tried using `extractall` but I don't know how to deal with the `Null` values in the columns.

Comment: You're probably best off by replacing the NULL values by something relevant for the column; perhaps an empty string. Alternatively, you could remove rows with NULLs.

Comment: I tried populating the ```null``` values with a dummy string but I get the error 
```TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index``` when using ```extractall```

my code is as follows:
```frame['desc'] = frame.category.str.extractall(r'(?<={})(.*?)(?={})'.format("desc", "lang"))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['category']=[[{'id':'4g', 'desc':'med', 'lang':'en-US'}, {'id':'nr', 'desc':'hos', 'lang':'en-US'}],
               [{'id':'hh', 'desc':'disc', 'lang':'en-US'}],'NULL']
df['category']=df['category'].apply(lambda x : ', '.join([l['desc'] for l in x]) if x!='NULL' else 'NULL')
df
    category
0   med, hos
1   disc
2   NULL
```

Comment: Good one. You used dictionary to get the values while we were over-thinking & using regex!

Comment: Your code works exactly as intended for the sample data frame `df`. However, when I try to do the same on my data frame, I get the error message `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.